# how to build only a docker image with code changes in Codebuild to send to ecr

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild, monorepo, amazon-ecr

I am working with a bitbucket monorepository that sends the code to codebuild and there I create the docker images and then send them to the ECR, what I want is that only the images that have modified their code are built, so as not to send the same images to ECR repositories and save Codebuild time (it's about 16 images per push)

[image: Reference image]

**My Buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.2
phases: 
  install:  
    commands: 
      - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2&
      - timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
  pre_build: 
    commands: 
    - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR.... 
    - aws --version
    # update the following line with your own region
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
    - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
    - IMAGE_TAG=latest
    - REPOSITORY_URI=23685584657641.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-bitbucket-to-ecr-1
    - REPOSITORY_URI_2=34585584995410.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-bitbucket-to-ecr-2
  build: 
    commands: 
    - echo Build started on `date` 
    - echo Building the Docker image... 
    # update the following line with the name of your own ECR repository
    - ls -a
    - pwd
    - cd api
    - pwd
    - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI_2:latest -f Dockerfile.google .
    - cd ..
    - pwd
    - echo ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
    - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest -f Dockerfile.lambda .
    - docker run -d --rm --name lambda_test_container $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
    - docker ps -a
    - docker exec lambda_test_container python -m flake8 /var/task/lambda_function.py /var/task/test_lambda_function.py
    - docker exec lambda_test_container python -m unittest /var/task/test_lambda_function.py
    - docker exec lambda_test_container python -m black /var/task/lambda_function.py /var/task/test_lambda_function.py
    - docker stop lambda_test_container
    # update the following line with the URI of your own ECR repository (view the Push Commands in the console)
    - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
    - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI_2:latest $REPOSITORY_URI_2:$IMAGE_TAG 
  post_build: 
    commands: 
    - echo Build completed on `date` 
    - echo pushing to repo
    # update the following line with the URI of your own ECR repository
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI_2:latest
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI_2:$IMAGE_TAG

    - echo Writing image definitions file... 
    #- printf '[{"ImageURI":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imageDetail.json
    - printf '{"ImageURI":"%s"}' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imageDetail.json
artifacts:
  files:
    - imageDetail.json
```

I try to pull the images from the repositories to compare but that also takes time